# How to fix duplicate error on ListView after click Back button?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

duplicate happening only after click the back button.

I uploaded my fully listview code in github.
[listview code](https://github.com/bhanuka96/ios_login/blob/master/listview.dart)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
Widget createListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

// ... 

      children: List.generate(values.length, (index) {
```

has a wrong length.

Be aware that your **build** method can get called at any time (and when you navigate it will get called for sure).

Therefore your

```
getRegister1()
```

gets called many times and thus you need to investigate this method more since the code behind your *HelperDatabase1* is not provided.

( maybe here is your issue ...

```
var catLocal = (await HelperDatabase1().displayDefCatRelation())
var defCatLocal = (await HelperDatabase1().display()) +

cat.add(catLocal[i].c);  // maybe this actually saves in your db/cache
```

but I can't be sure of it
)

---

Another thing you should look into is that your **getRegister1()** should be "previously obtained".
Check this snipper from the [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _calculation, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return Text('Press button to start.');
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Awaiting result...');
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
)
```